# Erro ao validar se o Index selecionado do datagridView é null

Tags: c#, datagridview, índices

Estou com dificuldade na alimentação de uma dataGridView com objetos, onde preciso listar propriedades de outro objeto. como por exemplo:

PRODUTO.CODIGO, PRODUTO.DESCRICAO, PEDIDO.VALORUNITARIO.

A unica solução que encontrei para tal tratamento, seria a disponibilizada neste

http://www.macoratti.net/16/10/c_dgvobj1.htm não sei se seria a forma ideal,

pois, atribuo todos meus objetos a uma lista de objeto, e aplico na datasource da dataGridView . onde da certo a apresentação, 
       Porém, meu **PROBLEMA** se inicia no momento que vou efetuar a remoção de algum objeto da dataGridView , através da função, Remove, de uma lista.

```
Lista.Remove(dtGridMaterial.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as Objeto)
```

O Objeto é removido corretamente da dataGridView , porém após a remoção, o evento abaixo é acionado:

```
  private void dtGridMaterial_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((dtGridMaterial.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem != null) && (dtGridMaterial.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName.Contains(".")))
            {
                e.Value = BindProperty(dtGridMaterial.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem, dtGridMaterial.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName);
            }
        }
```

Onde é feita a validação se o campo que defini na propriedade DataPropertyName do DataGridView possui o ponto (".").Assim posso identificar as propriedades das outras classes, conforme é explicado no link acima.

o Resultado, final é a seguinte excessão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entendo que o indice que estou tentando validar no evento já foi removido pela função remove. porém não sei tratar o problema. preciso de ajuda, desde já agradeço.

** COMPLEMENTO, Funções utilizadas

Remover da Grid

```
        {
            ObraNegocio obraNegocio = new ObraNegocio(gObra);
           obraNegocio.RemoverMaterialObra(dtGridMaterial.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as MaterialObra);
            gObra.RemoverMaterial(dtGridMaterial.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem as MaterialObra); 
        }
```

Remover da Lista

```
public void RemoverMaterial(MaterialObra materialObra)
        {
            ListamaterialObras.Remove(materialObra);
        }
```

Preencher dados da Grid

```
public void PreencherGridMaterial()
        {
            try
            {
                dtGridMaterial.DataSource = null;
                dtGridMaterial.DataSource = gObra.ListamaterialObras;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("erro " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Evento CellFormating, como falei, para apresentar dados de outras classes vinculadas as grid.

```
 private void dtGridMaterial_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((dtGridMaterial.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem != null) && (dtGridMaterial.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName.Contains(".")))
            {
                e.Value = BindProperty(dtGridMaterial.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem, dtGridMaterial.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName);
            }
        }
```

[image: Quando acesso via janela imediata]

Comment: só com esse trecho de código não dá para adivinhar... `Lista` é o `DataSource` da sua grid view? onde está o resto do método para remover? apresente um [mcve]

Comment: Exatamente isso que passei, eu atribuo objetos de uma lista de objeto, e o datasource da grid recebe essa lista. 

na função remover, retiro um objeto especifico da lista, e atribuo novamente ao datasource, para atualização

```C#
   public void RemoverMaterial(MaterialObra materialObra)
        {
            ListamaterialObras.Remove(materialObra);
        }

        List<MaterialObra> listaMaterialObra;
```

Comment: Mas isso não está incluído na pergunta... adicione o trecho em que você atribui o datasource e o atualiza após a remoção.

Comment: Editei a publicação, postando todas as funções utilizadas